# Kinect 2.0 for Xbox One to PC USB 3.0 keeps disconnecting?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, xbox-one

Does anyone here use USB 3.0, and can tell me why when I plugin my Xbox One Kinect 2.0 USB 3.0 cable into the computer, why it keeps sporadically disconnecting and reconnecting even though I downloaded all the windows updates, all the graphics card updates, all the firmware updates, etc...? And YES, I tried several different Ports. It's not broke. I got it new for Christmas.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - I purchased a Kienect for Windows v2 and the USB driver seems to drop in and out maybe 20 times a day. How frequently does yours drop out?

Comment: I have the same issue. Windows 10, Kinect 2.0 for Xbox One. The Kinect will connect for about 5 seconds, then disconnect for the next 5 seconds. This will repeat on an infinite cycle. I have the latest "Partner" drivers (to enable Windows Hello) and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 15):

After fighting with this for weeks, I finally found the root of my frequent disconnects. At some point, I had disabled the **Xbox NUI Sensor Microphone Array** to eliminate a feedback loop:

**Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Sound > Recording**

After re-enabling the Kinect microphone, the Kinect stopped disconnecting.

To eliminate the feedback loop, I reduced the Kinect microphone's level setting to 0. You can get to the level setting from the **Recording** tab in the **Sound** dialog. Select the **Xbox NUI Sensor Microphone Array** and click the **Properties** button. From there, select the Levels tab.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I kept trying every thing for days, and finally the issue turned to be from the kinect AC adaptor... I tried it with the official windows sdk and developer toolkit, when I attempted one of the example codes the issue persists to appear but with a clear message asking to plug the power cord in, though the adaptor is brand new!!

I searched for some information a bout the AC adaptor and it seems that there is a problem with the adaptor, and most importantly the Kinect manual states that any unoriginal adaptors may cause the device to fail - also the manual says that original AC adaptor power output is 12V-1.1A while the one I have is rated 12V-1.08A (no big deal but who knows)

[Kinect for Xbox 360 freezes and disconnects from USB after running Processing SimpleOpenNi depth image example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29359425/kinect-for-xbox-360-freezes-and-disconnects-from-usb-after-running-processing-si/29441146#29441146)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem,too. My system using pci-e usb 3 gen 2 and in windows 10 v1903 and kinect sdk 2 ... and all thing OK.. worked correctly .then after a date .reapetdly disconnect and restart.
at last ..I found this problem on my system...
I disabled sound using in windows setting.
I enabled this item in setting and all things became OK.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Read this, if you use an USB3.0 expansion card in a PCIe slot.**

In my case I had connected the adaptor to an USB3.0 card (Transcent PDU3). After some hours research I discovered that the mainboard (MSI K9a2 Platinum) had Gen2 PCIe for the PCI-E x16 slots, but not for the PCI-E x1 I had plugged the USB card into. After switching to a PCI-E x16 slot, the constant disconnecting was over.

*Don't confuse PCIe version and USB version here. For a Kinect 2.0 you need USB 3.0 and for USB 3.0 to run at super speed, you need PCIe 2.0 (or Gen2).*

**Testing PCIe version**

You can use [GPU-Z](http://www.gpu-z.de/) to determine which PCIe-Version the slot has where you got your graphics card plugged in -- let the mouse pointer hover over the bus interface field and wait for the tooltip and it will reveal the PCI-e version of your graphics card as well as the one of your mainboard. If you confirm it is Gen2 (or PCI 2.0) try to use that slot to put a confirmed-as-working-with-the-Kinect-2-USB3.0-card in it. (Having onboard graphics or a second PCI-Ex16 slot will definitely come in handy here).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the USB 3.0 version, older machines won't run it. You need USB "3.1" and controllers usually manufactured after 2013 have it. It's often mislabelled as USB 3.0 in marketing material.  USB 3.1 is also known as "SuperSpeed" or "SS10" which goes up to 10 Gbit/s. USB 3.0 "only" transports at 5 Gbit/s.

I have two five years old big rigs (Z68X-UD3H-B3, i7-3770K, and a 970a-D3, FX-8350) and it constantly disconnects. Both have 2011 board technology.
I also have two laptops, a VAIO and a Lenovo, which were built after 2013 (when they changed to USB 3.1) and it runs fine on both of those machines.
I too suspected the power supply at one point, nope, I thought I had a broken Kinect (bought a second, nope, now I own two.)
Other things to check:
- You might be able to use a USB 3.1 PCI card as long your MotherB will carry it.
- Remember to load the Kinect SDK 2.0 and also update the driver to the 2016 driver (SDK 2.0 comes with the 2014 driver).
- Remember USB 3.x is the "Blue" USB plug not the black.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a case of requirements increasing beyond the capabilities of USB3.0!
Its also not a problem with Win10 1809 or KinectSDK 1409.
It will disconnect if your apps have no access to either microphone or camera.
You can check or reset your settings the easiest with a free program called OOSU10.
Runs fine on my 2012 laptop.

If your problem is that the Kinect Configuration Verifier does not start at all, then this is caused by having disabled the printer spooler service.