# Kinect for Xbox 360 freezes and disconnects from USB after running Processing SimpleOpenNi depth image example

Tags: linux, processing, kinect, ubuntu-14.04, simple-openni

please help

I've been trying to set up kinect for XBOX 360 to run on ubuntu in order to start developing an application to control a humanoid robot. for the past four days I've been searching , downloading , installing and trying dozens of libraries and drivers to get the kinect to work on Ubuntu. in the beginning none was working and I was only able to read the RGB camera with "Camorama" and "guvcview" no matter what library or driver I attempted to run.. Finally, I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu and installed libfreenect libraries using synaptic (I'm kinda newbie) and I also installed the following packages

https://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/downloads/detail?name=OpenNI_NITE_Installer-Linux64-0.27.zip&can=4&q=

along with Processing 2.0 and SimpleOpenNi-0.27

I start Processing -> examples -> OpenNi -> DepthImage & RUN
and the kinect starts for 3 to 10 seconds giving the image below some times along with the RGB image and some times with out it, then the frame freezes, and when I try listing the USB devices ($lsusb) there is no Kinect camera or audio devices listed, so the Kinect must be unplugged from the Adaptor and USB and then re-inserted and the problem still occur after running the sketch.

Attempted solutions:

1- removing and black listing gspca kernel module

2- disabling USB auto-suspend

but the problem still occur...

I'm using Kinect for XBOX 360 with (12V - 1.08A) USB AC Power Adapter 
http://www.walmart.com/ip/INSTEN-USB-AC-Power-Adapter-For-Microsoft-Xbox-360-Kinect-Sensor/28882271

My laptop is : DELL Inspiron.1525 Intel Core2Duo RAM 2GB

Running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS ,, Release:  14.04 ,, Codename:  trusty

Can any one help me please!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and after I used Kinect With windows, I found that the problem was from the Kinect itself.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I tried it with the official windows sdk and developer toolkit, when I attempted one of the example codes the issue persists to appear but with a clear message asking to plug the power cord in, though the adaptor is brand new!!

Comment: I checked those sites for some informations a bout the AC adaptor and it seems that there is a problem with the adaptor, and most importantly the Kinect manual states that any unoriginal adaptors may cause the device to fail - also the manual says that original AC adaptor power output is 12V-1.1A while the one I have is rated 12V-1.08A (no big deal but who knows) on the meanwhile this sites: http://goo.gl/OUiaCx
states that 2A is prefered!! and some says 4A would work !!!

Comment: @MohamedAbdElRaouf i have the adaptor with 2V 2.67A and i try to connect the sensor to windows 10 VM and it keeps also disconnecting

Comment: @Hany : 2V is not sufficient by all means!! use the original adapter,,, i'm not sure if the vm can cause problems as i never tested it ... but my advice to you is to try it on a native machine with its official sdk and drivers just to make sure that the device is intact ... in my case after trying several days it turned that the device it self was broken...

Comment: @MohamedAbdElRaouf i added an answer with screenshot of the adaptor , it's 12V , it was a typing mistake

Answer (score 0):

The following tips will help you get started using your Kinect:

1. If a non-Microsoft driver for the Kinect is installed on your computer, the Kinect for Windows drivers might not install or function correctly. To fix this, uninstall the non-Microsoft drivers before installing the Kinect for Windows SDK.
2. Connect the power supply for the Kinect to an external power source; if the Kinect has only power from the USB connection, it will be minimally functional and light the LED, but it must be connected to an external power source to be fully functional.
3. No tools are required for calibration of audio and video.
4. Your Kinect should be the only device plugged into a USB hub on your computer. If you have more than one Kinect, connect them to different USB controllers. If 2 hubs are connected to the same controller, only 1 Kinect can work at a time.
5. The Kinect is protected from overheating by a fan. It is controlled by the sensor's firmware, which turns off the camera at 90 degrees Celsius. There is no software interface for applications to control the fan.
6. Reasonable lighting, neither extremely dark nor extremely bright, is important for capturing images with the RGB camera. Incandescent, fluorescent, and natural lighting provide no special obstacles, but do not point an intense or constant light source at the camera because this can blind the RGB sensor.
7. The depth sensor functions adequately in typical and reduced lighting, although in near darkness there is increased noise in the signal.
8. The depth sensor reads depth information from reflected light. Objects that are highly reflective (mirrors and shiny metal) or highly absorptive (fluffy and/or dark materials) may not be registered by the depth sensor as successfully as other objects.

> for detailed instructions on Setting Up a Kinect Sensor please follow
>   : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855356