# Freenect on fedora: Number of devices found: 0

Tags: fedora, openkinect

Hye. I'm trying to use a Kinect for XBox one on fedora 21. I installed freenect/openKinect using the official repository.

When i plug the Kinect on my computer `dmesg | tail` gives:

```
[ 2877.198513] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 2877.400501] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 2877.400512] usb 2-2.1: USB disconnect, device number 7
[ 2881.158423] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 2881.574851] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 2881.589681] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=02d9
[ 2881.589690] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2881.589694] usb 1-2: Product: NuiSensor Adaptor      
[ 2881.589698] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation  
[ 2881.591297] hub 1-2:1.0: USB hub found
[ 2881.591616] hub 1-2:1.0: 1 port detected
[ 2884.550626] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=02d9
[ 2884.550638] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2884.550643] usb 2-2: Product: NuiSensor Adaptor      
[ 2884.550648] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation  
[ 2884.551941] hub 2-2:1.0: USB hub found
[ 2884.552474] hub 2-2:1.0: 1 port detected
```

and `lsusb` gives:

```
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 5986:0315 Acer, Inc 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 045e:02c4 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 045e:02d9 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 045e:02d9 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

but i can't find any knew device knew device `/dev/` and when i try the demonstration program it doesn't find the device and show:

```
Kinect camera test
Number of devices found: 0
```

Did anyone succeed to use freenect on fedora?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using appropriate AC adaptor to connect the sensor to PC?!

I had a similar issue and I kept trying every thing for days, and finally the issue turned to be from the kinect AC adaptor... I tried it with the official windows sdk and developer toolkit, when I attempted one of the example codes the issue persists to appear but with a clear message asking to plug the power cord in, though the adaptor is brand new!!

I searched for some information a bout the AC adaptor and it seems that there is a problem with the adaptor, and most importantly the Kinect manual states that any unoriginal adaptors may cause the device to fail - also the manual says that original AC adaptor power output is 12V-1.1A while the one I have is rated 12V-1.08A (no big deal but who knows)

[Kinect for Xbox 360 freezes and disconnects from USB after running Processing SimpleOpenNi depth image example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29359425/kinect-for-xbox-360-freezes-and-disconnects-from-usb-after-running-processing-si/29441146#29441146)

Comment: I'm using the the adaptor coming with the "Kinect for Windows adaptor" so it's supposed to be good. Furthermore, we tried it on windows and it worked. I've digged a bit more in the problem and it seems that this model is not taken care of by libfreenect. You can see https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/issues/439 for more info.

Comment: You can try librekinect instead, it is a Small and fast kernel driver. Also for embedded devices like the raspberry pi! 

https://github.com/xxorde/librekinect